# Emacs dired how to set date/time format

Tags: emacs, dired

Now dired writes the last access date/time in the following format:

```
Jun 20 14:22
```

How to make it write:

```
20.06.2012 14:22
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one of these options:

### 1  you can set the appropriate variables.

> ```
>  (setq ls-lisp-format-time-list  '("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
>       ls-lisp-use-localized-time-format t)
> ```

[image]

explanation: The `ls-lisp-format-time-list` is a list of two format strings, which work as they do with the `format-time-string` function.  There are two, because by default emacs is set up to display "recent" files with a higher-resolution timestamp than "older" files, where the recent vs older threshold is 6 months (I think). The first is the format used for recent files; the latter is for older files.

I never liked the default behavior; I just want the files to be displayed the same way.  So I set the list to use the same time format for newer and older files.

### 2 You can redefine the function `ls-lisp-format-time`.

For example, if I do this:

```
(defun ls-lisp-format-time (file-attr time-index now)
  "################")
```

Then dired looks like this:

[image]

The original definition of the function is in ls-lisp.el.

Comment: If using GNU ls, you can concat "--time-style \"+%d.%m.%Y %H:%M\"" to dired-listing-switches. (--time-style=\"... space ...\" doesn't parse correctly -- an emacs bug) If you want different formats for recent and non-recent files, you can separate them with a newline.